# HTTP Status Codes for declined payment

Tags: http-status-codes, worldpay

I'm working on an E-Commerce site and this involves sending card information to an enpoint. This does many things such as query the database for costs and sends off this information to WorldPay. If the payment response is `success` the repose status is `200`.

If the payment is not successful, there are two responses:

- `FAILED`
- `ERROR`

I assume that these would be `400` but I am not certain. I also wonder if `FAILED` and `ERROR` would be different statuses?

The WorldPay API displays the following information

> SUCCESS : Simulation of a successful payment
>
> FAILED : Simulation of a[sic] unsuccessful payment
>
> ERROR : Simulation of an error

Source: https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/docs/testing

It is unclear what the diffence between `FAILED` and `ERROR`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Worldpay API, but I make this difference between unsuccessful and error :

- Failed/Unsuccessful : the business process ran normally and it ended with an unsuccessful payment : For example, bank refuses the payment because the weekly limit has been reached, the card is blocked.
- Error : the business process has failed due to technical problem : the bank API is unreachable, the merchant ID is unknown, the certificate is outdated.